# How to dentify what files or directories are modified when a debian package is installed?

Tags: files, apt, software-installation

If I do a `sudo apt install example-package -y` then the apt program will pull the deb file from its repo and install it in the system.

Some program will have `conf` files inside `/etc` folder and its `executable` file will be in `/bin` and some other file may or may not be in `/usr/share/example-package` folder.

**Is there anyway to get the list of created files / folders that took place during such an installation?**

Comment: Of course, maintainer scripts could additionally create or modify files, and it's in general not possible to always predict what the scripts will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From `man dpkg`:

```
-L, --listfiles package-name...
    List files installed to your system from package-name.
```

Using your example, the command would be `dpkg -L example-package`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check the contents before installing a package, you can also go to `http://packages.debian.org/<package name>` then select the version of the package you wish to inspect, and then at the bottom of the page there will be a table of download links for that package for each architecture available. On the right-most column of that table, there are links labeled `[list of files]`. Click on the link matching your system architecture, and you'll see exactly what the package contains without even downloading it.

If you have already downloaded a `.deb` package, but haven't installed it yet, you can view its contents with `dpkg -c <package.deb>`. If you want to see what the package's post-install script would do, you can use `dpkg -I <package.deb> postinst`. Instead of `postinst`, you can also use keywords `preinst`, `postrm` and `prerm` to view the respective scripts, if they exist in the package.